# auto intendation on newline doesn't stay at same indentation for python docstring

Tags: indentation, python, doc-strings

```
Ubuntu 19.10
emacs 26.3 from system repos
I do use elpy and evil-mode
```

In general when I am editing python code, indentation works just fine.  However, when I am editing doc-strings, when I type enter to get a newline, it goes all the way to column 1. (fill-paragraph) and (indent-region) will both fix the indentation, but its annoying and I'm wondering if its possible to get emacs to respect the indentation that I'm using.

below is an example of what I mean

```
def func():
    """a dummy function

    if I start typing here, then type enter,
then it moves here...,

    however if I type here... lorem ipsum lorem ipsum blah blah blah, need
characters to get past 80, now if I hit M-q, or highlight the region and then
(indent-region), then it changes it to:

    however if I type here... lorem ipsum lorem ipsum blah blah blah, need
    characters to get past 80, now if I hit M-q, or highlight the region and
    then (indent-region), then it changes it to:

    """
```